# CakePHP FindAllBy Conditions for image gallery

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How do I tell CakePHP 1.3 to pull all images that have the same gallery_id matching the gallery_id  of the current Image View? I am trying to find all images for a Gallery using FindAllByGalleryId. In the view there is one big picture for the image view, and thumbnails below it of all other images in the same gallery.

Everything works when I enter an actual Gallery ID number (as shown here), but that Gallery ID number changes depending on which Gallery is being viewed - so I don't want it to be set to a specific number - I want it to match the gallery_id of the image being viewed.

```
$this->set(
    'all_images',
    $this->Image->findAllByGalleryId('2')

);
```

What is needed is to set the current gallery_id as the variable and then tell the Find conditions to match it. Problem is that I don't have the right syntax, so the error comes up that the gallery_id variable does not exist.

I have tried setting find conditions to 'Image.gallery_id' => '$gallery_id' and similar stabs at identifying the current item's gallery_id to be matched, but I'm clueless after working at this for some time. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$this->set('all_images', $this->Image->findAllByGalleryId($this->Image->data['Image']['gallery_id']));`

Comment: Thanks, Francois... I get the error message-- Undefined variable: gallery_id [images_controller.php]

Comment: @Jamie - Can you post the controller action that displays a gallery in your question?

Comment: @Jamie - I think I may have misread your question. Try this: `$this->Image->findAllByGalleryId($this->Image->data['gallery_id']);`.

Comment: Awesome! I found the solution between both your answer and YonoRan's:  $this->set('all_images',   $this->Image->findAllByGalleryId($this->Image->data['Image']['gallery_id']));                        A million thank yous Francois!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you get the information about the image (the large one being displayed) your also getting the gallery ID.

So basically in the findByAllGalleryID you should put in the data that corresponds to the gallery ID, something like: $this->data['Image']['gallery_id'];

That way no matter what image your viewing, you should get a list of all the other images in the same gallery.

Comment: Thank you so much YonoRan! Between you and Francois, I am saved many headaches.